# Resolving concrete types when using polymorphism in Autofac

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism, autofac

Consider the following code:

```
public interface IFileBackup
{
    Task Backup(byte[] file);
}

public class BackUpMechanismA : IFileBackup
{
    //Implementation
    public async Task Backup(byte[] file)
    {
        //Attempts to backup using mechanism A
    }
}

public class BackUpMechanismB : IFileBackup
{
    //Implementation
    public async Task Backup(byte[] file)
    {
        //Attempts to backup using mechanism B
    }
}
```

Then the calling class looks like this:

```
public class Caller
{
    private readonly IFileBackup _backupA;
    private readonly IFileBackup _backupB;

    public Caller(IFileBackup backupA, IFileBackup backupB)
    {
        _backupA = backupA;
        _backupB = backupB;
    }


     public async Task BackupFile(byte[] file)
     {
         try
         {
             await _backupA.Backup(file);
         }
         catch(SomeException)
         {
             await _backupB.Backup(file);
         }
     }
}
```

So what I'm trying to do here is to use polymorphism. So both `BackupMechanismA` and `BackupMechanismB` implements the `Backup` method in their own way. In the caller I want to attempt the first mechanism and if that doesn't work we catch an exception and try the second approach.

I'm having trouble resolving the correct implementations using `Autofac`. I have tried with:

`builder.RegisterType<BackupMechanismA>().As<IFileBackup>().AsSelf();
 builder.RegisterType<BackupMechanismB>().As<IFileBackUp>().AsSelf();`

But this won't work because I still need to tell the caller which of the types to resolve. How do I do that in the caller?

Also, I'm in doubt whether this design is really the right design to go with. Before this design I just had one class with two different methods, one for mechanism A and one for mechanism B and then the caller would just call the different methods in the try catch. So I wanted to refactor this because the class got quite big and I wanted to separate the two different mechanisms into their own classes.

So, can I resolve this using Autofac? And is it the right design to go with for this scenario?

Comment: did you find your answer?

Comment: @Jogge Yes I did but I changed my design so I didn't use polymorphism anyway. I accepted the answer which I think was the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Jogge that iterating `IFileBackup`s would be a better option, but creating an interface for each type is a no go. Instead, you could add a class which provides `IEnumerable<IFileBackup>` (an aggregate). For example:

```
public class BackupBundle : IEnumerable<IFileBackup>
{
    private readonly List<IFileBackup> _backups = new List<IFileBackup>();

    // default constructor creates default implementations
    public BackupBundle()
        : this(new List<IFileBackup> {new BackUpMechanismA(), new BackUpMechanismB()}) {}

    // allow users to add custom backups
    public BackupBundle(IEnumerable<IFileBackup> backups)
    {
        foreach (var backup in backups)
            Add(backup);
    }

    public void Add(IFileBackup backup)
    {
        if (backup == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(backup));
        _backups.Add(backup);
    }

    public IEnumerator<IFileBackup> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var backup in _backups)
            yield return backup;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class Caller
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IFileBackup> _backups;

    public Caller(IEnumerable<IFileBackup> backups)
    {
        _backups = backups ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(backups));
    }

    public async Task BackupFile(byte[] file)
    {
        foreach (var b in _backups)
        {
            try
            {
                await b.Backup(file);
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Registration can be done as follows:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(new BackupBundle()).As<IEnumerable<IFileBackup>>();
builder.RegisterType<Caller>();
```

which allows you to resolve by class name:

```
var caller = scope.Resolve<Caller>();
```

As you see, the `BackupBundle` has a dependency of `BackUpMechanismA` and `BackUpMechanismB`. You could get rid of it by introducing another layer of abstraction but I'd prefer not to do that. My main concern would be to make `Caller` more robust. You might want to introduce retry logic, timeouts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering with a name and then resolve using the name:

```
builder.RegisterType<BackupMechanismA>().Named<IFileBackup>("BackUpMechanismA");
builder.RegisterType<BackupMechanismB>().Named<IFileBackUp>("BackUpMechanismB");

_backupA = container.ResolveNamed<IFileBackUp> 
("BackUpMechanismA"); 
_backupB = container.ResolveNamed<IFileBackUp> 
("BackUpMechanismB");
```

Resolve the instances during runtime, rather than injecting through the constructor. This will let you resolve to the respective type, as needed.
Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

To make your design work, you can try the next approach:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<BackUpMechanismA>().Keyed<IFileBackup>("A");
    builder.RegisterType<BackUpMechanismB>().Keyed<IFileBackup>("B");
    builder.RegisterType<Caller>()
            .WithParameter((p, ctx) => p.Position == 0, (p, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<IFileBackup>("A"))
            .WithParameter((p, ctx) => p.Position == 1, (p, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<IFileBackup>("B"));
    IContainer container = builder.Build();

    var caller = container.Resolve<Caller>();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

However in my opinion you probably don't need such a polymorphism here. It will be much more obvious and descriptive to implement something like this:

```
public async Task BackupFile(byte[] file)
{
    try
    {
        await BackUpToAmazonS3(file);
    }
    catch (AmazonS3LoadingException)
    {
        await BackUpToLocalDisk(file);
    }
}
```

In this example it is obvious what is going on. And there in `BackUpToAmazonS3` you can use some injected `AmazonS3FileBackUp` and in `BackUpToLocalDisk` use `LocalDiskFileBackUp` or whatever. The point is that you don't need a polymorphism, when you don't plan to change the implementation. In your context it should be clear? that you try to put backup to some remote storage, and then, if it fails, put in on local disk. You don't need to hide the meaning here. This is your logic and should be clear, when you read the code, I suppose. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, you're better off by creating an interface for each type:

```
public interface IFileBackup
{
    Task Backup(byte[] file);
}

public interface IBackUpMechanismA : IFileBackup
{
}

public class BackUpMechanismA : IBackUpMechanismA
{
    //...
}

public interface IBackUpMechanismB : IFileBackup
{
}

public class BackUpMechanismB : IBackUpMechanismB
{
    //...
}
```

If you don't want that, what you could do is getting injected a list of `IFileBackup` and just iterate them. If you register BackUpMechanismA first it will be the first in the list. I'm not sure if this is guaranteed, you have to look it up.

```
public class Caller
{
    private readonly ICollection<IFileBackup> _fileBackups;

    public Caller(ICollection<IFileBackup> fileBackups)
    {
        _fileBackups = fileBackups;
    }

    public async Task BackupFile(byte[] file)
    {
        foreach (var fileBackup in _fileBackups)
        {
            try
            {
                await fileBackup.Backup(file);
                break;
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```